# How to not merge some file into master by default?

Tags: git

I have some file `config.cfg` I want in source control.
Every developer makes their own changes to that file, pushes those changes to their private branch, but usually doesn't want to merge those changes to master.

I don't want to go through cherry picking every merge.

I want to have this specific file not merged by default, unless I positively specify to merge it.

How can this be done?

Comment: What you ask is not how git works - why is a file that has to be modified a tracked file?

Comment: I think there is no way to check it in to a branch but not merge. What I mostly do in my projects is checking in a `config.cfg.example` and `.gitignore` the `config.cfg`. For my most recent project I even made the local build copy the example file to local if it did not yet exist.

Comment: I think there is no way to do this. A typical example is a cmake file which freezes dependencies. Before merging to master, we manually unfreeze the dependencies (checkout the original file from master) to your dev branch and then perform the merge.